# converting java code to beanshell sampler (JMETER)

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;


public class createFXRates_Files {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
        int totalrecords = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int randomrow;
        String FileName = null;


        //Creating a file 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date date = new Date();
        FileName = "FXrates."+sdf.format(date);
        File outfile = new File("C:\\SAMIR\\Projects\\DataHub_BMO\\JAVATEST\\"+FileName);
        if(outfile.exists()) {
            outfile.delete();
        }
        outfile.createNewFile();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile);

        //Reading a sampler file
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\SAMIR\\Projects\\DataHub_BMO\\FXrates.20190903"));// sample file path to scanner
        ArrayList<String> rows= new ArrayList<String>();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String data = sc.nextLine();
            rows.add(data);
        }

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<totalrecords; i++) {

            randomrow = random.nextInt(10000);
            System.out.println(""+Integer.toString(randomrow));

            fw.write(""+rows.get(randomrow)+"\n");
            System.out.println(rows.get(randomrow));
        }

        sc.close();
        fw.close();

    }
}
```

I need to convert above java code in a bean shell sampler in jmeter. tried doing it resulted into **"In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;   import java.util.ArrayLis . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 27, column 39.**
" error. it seems like compiler cannot resolve for Collection classes. even though code include an import of "*import java.util.ArrayList;*"

Answer (score 1):

Beanshell doesn't support [diamond operators](https://www.codenuclear.com/diamond-operator-type-inference-generic-instance-creation-java/) in particular and stuck at [Java SE 1.5 language level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html) in general therefore you need to remove these `<String>` bits in order to make the code working.

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, in this case you will not have to change anything, moreover [Groovy has much better performance comparing with Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) and adds some ["syntax sugar"](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use JSR223 Sampler instead of Beanshell Sampler. 
In JSR223 Sampler: Put the following code in script area

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.*;

    int totalrecords = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int randomrow;
    String FileName = null;


    //Creating a file 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date date = new Date();
    FileName = "FXrates."+sdf.format(date);
    File outfile = new File("C:\\SAMIR\\Projects\\DataHub_BMO\\JAVATEST\\"+FileName);
    if(outfile.exists()) {
        outfile.delete();
    }
    outfile.createNewFile();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile);

    //Reading a sampler file
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\SAMIR\\Projects\\DataHub_BMO\\FXrates.20190903"));// sample file path to scanner
    ArrayList<String> rows= new ArrayList<String>();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String data = sc.nextLine();
        rows.add(data);
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i<totalrecords; i++) {

        randomrow = random.nextInt(10000);
        log.info(""+Integer.toString(randomrow));

        fw.write(""+rows.get(randomrow)+"\n");
      log.info(rows.get(randomrow));
    }

    sc.close();
    fw.close();
```